# Pandas: groupby unstack, duplicate index error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble pivoting/reshaping my dataframe. After a `melt()` operation, I have the following df:

```
|----|------|------|------------|
| ID | Rank | Var  | Val        |
|----|------|------|------------|
|  1 |   1  | date | 2020-01-01 |
|----|------|------|------------|
|  1 |   2  | date | 2020-02-01 |
|----|------|------|------------|
|  2 |   1  | date | 2020-01-01 |
|----|------|------|------------|
|  2 |   2  | date | 2020-02-01 |
|----|------|------|------------|
|  1 |   1  | amt  | 320        |
|----|------|------|------------|
|  1 |   2  | amt  | 480        |
|----|------|------|------------|
|  2 |   1  | amt  | 620        |
|----|------|------|------------|
|  2 |   2  | amt  | 400        |
|----|------|------|------------|
```

The result I am looking for would be to convert the rank values into columns:

```
|----|------|------------|------------|
| ID | Var  | 1          | 2          |
|----|------|------------|------------|
| 1  | date | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-01 |
|    |------|------------|------------|
|    | amt  | 320        | 480        |
|----|------|------------|------------|
| 2  | date | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-01 |
|    |------|------------|------------|
|    | amt  | 620        | 400        |
|----|------|------------|------------|
```

Immediately trying to `unstack(level='Rank')` results in a

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Ok, we do have duplicate `IDs`, let's `groupby` to consolidate:

`df.set_index(['ID', 'Rank']).groupby(['ID', 'Rank']).apply(lambda x: x)`

The `apply()` is just so we can return a dataframe and preview the results, which are:

```
|----|------|------|------------|
| ID | Rank | Var  | Val        |
|----|------|------|------------|
|  1 |   1  | date | 2020-01-01 |
|    |------|------|------------|
|    |   1  | amt  | 320        |
|    |------|------|------------|
|    |   2  | date | 2020-02-01 |
|    |------|------|------------|
|    |   2  | amt  | 480        |
|----|------|------|------------|
|  2 |   1  | date | 2020-01-01 |
|    |------|------|------------|
|    |   2  | date | 2020-02-01 |
|    |------|------|------------|
|    |   1  | amt  | 620        |
|    |------|------|------------|
|    |   2  | amt  | 400        |
|----|------|------|------------|
```

This is closer. Now we just need to convert Rank into cols:

`df.set_index(['ID', 'Rank']).groupby(['ID', 'Rank']).apply(lambda x: x).unstack(level='Rank')`

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

????

I also tried using `pivot_table`, but not all of the columns are numeric (the above example is simplified, but you can see date in here, which throws off pivot_table).

I seem to be just one method away, but I've tried unstacking, reindexing, pivoting, `explode()`-ing, I just can't figure out this last part...

How can I get the desired dataframe?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you use pivot? `df.pivot(['ID', 'Var'], 'Rank', 'Val')` or are the combinations of ID and Var that will cause the same error?

Comment: @It_is_Chris, thanks for the help. The error that occurs then is `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`.

Comment: You are not aggregating any data with `pivot` do you mean `pivot_table`?

Comment: @It_is_Chris, you are right, I accidentally thought you meant `pivot_table`. The answer by @ Aviad_Rozenhek worked, however, I do want to see if a simple pivot would work as well. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue is that the index keys must be unique to unstack.

**first, let's recreate this toy example**

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

df= pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Rank','Var', 'Val'],  data=[
    [1,1,'date', '2020-01-01'],
    [1,2,'date','2020-02-01'],
    [2,1,'date','2020-02-01'],
    [2,2,'date','2020-02-01'],
    [1,1,'amt',320],
    [1,2,'amt',480],
    [2,1,'amt',620],
    [2,2,'amt',400],
])

df = df.set_index(['ID', 'Rank'])
display(df)
```

**now, lets solve**

lets put unique keys in the index, namely the `ID` and `Var` fields.
now unstacking is trivial

```
df.set_index('Var', append=True).unstack('Rank')
```

Comment: You got it. This worked. Thank you so much for your help!